# List of files committed as part of merge from master in git

Tags: git, github

I'm working on a branch and recently I did a merge from master.

I want to know which files were modified as part of that commit? Any handy commands in GIT?

I do have the commit hash and when I'm trying to do 
`git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r f313111ecdbd9e8292ef1db51ea31d47c9a93202` it's returning nothing/

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First retrieve the SHA1 values of your last two commits using the following command:

```
git log -n 2
```

The top commit would be the merge commit, and second would be the commit before the merge commit. Then run the following command:

```
git diff --name-only <SHA1 value of merge commit> <SHA1 value of previous commit>
```

Comment: git log will show all the commits. Is there any command available to get only recent two commit hash only?

Comment: try git log -p -2

Comment: No it's showing the last changes committed(file level),not the commit hash

Comment: oh sorry, it would be git log -n 2

Comment: I'm using this commit hash inside a script. so with ```git log -n 2``` we get other info like Author, Date and Commit hash. I don't want those info. I want a single git command which only return 2 recent hashes which I can directly store in a variable

Comment: try this: git log -n 2 --pretty=format:"%h", but its only return first few chars of hash value, see if the git diff command works with these short version of SHA1 value.

Comment: Is there any command available through which I can know whether my latest commit was a merge from master commit or a normal commit?